# CSS Cross-Browser Animation Tips (Liquid / Gooey Checkbox Animation)

Tags: css, svg, safari, svg-animate, svg-filters

Regarding this custom CSS radio button (snippet below or @ https://codepen.io/Zaku/pen/xrKMgb)...

Why does Safari show blurred CSS element?

This works perfectly in Chrome but not Safari... demonstration below:

[image]

This is a big deal because most iPhone & Mac users default the Safari browser...

Any idea why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #af4671 0%, #a45cd1 100%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  filter: url('#gooey');
}

@keyframes circle__in {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }

  16% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.95, 1.05);
  }

  33% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05, 0.95);
  }

  66% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }

  83% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.98, 1.02);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}


input:checked + .circle {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: circle__in;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.circle {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: circle__out;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

.circle--outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid white;
}

.circle--inner {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
}

@keyframes circle--inner__in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.0);
  }

  80% {
    transform: scale(1.02);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

input:checked + .circle .circle--inner {
  transform-origin: 50% -20%;
  animation-name: circle--inner__in;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.85, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

@keyframes circle--inner__out {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  80% {
    transform: scale(0.19);
  }

  99% {
    transform: scale(0.21);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

.circle--inner {
  animation-name: circle--inner__out;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.85, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.circle--inner__1 { transform-origin: -12% -8%; }
.circle--inner__2 { transform-origin: -35% 50%; }
.circle--inner__3 { transform-origin: 60% 130%; }
.circle--inner__4 { transform-origin: 112% 90%; }
.circle--inner__5 { transform-origin: 75% -30%; }

// dribbble - twitter
.dribbble {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  img {
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
  }
}
.twitter {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  right: 64px;
  bottom: 14px;
  svg {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    fill: #1da1f2;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__1" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__2" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__3" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__4" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__5" ></div>
    <div class="circle--outer" ></div>
  </div>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <filter id="gooey">
        <feGaussianBlur
          in="SourceGraphic"
          result="blur"
          stdDeviation="3"
        />
        <feColorMatrix
          in="blur"
          mode="matrix"
          values="
            1 0 0 0 0
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 0 1 0 0
            0 0 0 18 -7
          "
          result="gooey"
        />
        <feBlend
          in2="gooey"
          in="SourceGraphic"
          result="mix"
        />
      </filter>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</label>


<!-- dribbble - twitter -->
<a class="dribbble" href="https://dribbble.com/TaminoMartinius" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-mark-2bd45f09c2fb58dbbfb44766d5d1d07c5a12972d602ef8b32204d28fa3dda554.svg" alt=""/>
</a>
<a class="twitter" target="_top" href="https://twitter.com/TaminoMartinius">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="72" height="72" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
    <path d="M67.812 16.141a26.246 26.246 0 0 1-7.519 2.06 13.134 13.134 0 0 0 5.756-7.244 26.127 26.127 0 0 1-8.313 3.176A13.075 13.075 0 0 0 48.182 10c-7.229 0-13.092 5.861-13.092 13.093 0 1.026.118 2.021.338 2.981-10.885-.548-20.528-5.757-26.987-13.679a13.048 13.048 0 0 0-1.771 6.581c0 4.542 2.312 8.551 5.824 10.898a13.048 13.048 0 0 1-5.93-1.638c-.002.055-.002.11-.002.162 0 6.345 4.513 11.638 10.504 12.84a13.177 13.177 0 0 1-3.449.457c-.846 0-1.667-.078-2.465-.231 1.667 5.2 6.499 8.986 12.23 9.09a26.276 26.276 0 0 1-16.26 5.606A26.21 26.21 0 0 1 4 55.976a37.036 37.036 0 0 0 20.067 5.882c24.083 0 37.251-19.949 37.251-37.249 0-.566-.014-1.134-.039-1.694a26.597 26.597 0 0 0 6.533-6.774z"/>
  </svg>    
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `<filter id="gooey">` with `<filter id="gooey" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">`

Color-interpolation-filters are set by default to sRGB in every browser except Safari.

#### Edit:

Reason behind using svg is to give a gooey effect which is visible if you observe the checkbox real closely. It won't degrade the quality of animation if its removed in this case as the change is minuscule. Just to tell to you the difference I changed the animation when the checkbox is checked from transform:scale() to translateX() and also enabled svg so when it would move up and down you would see the white circle is trying blend in the outer circle but when you remove the svg it won't blend in.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #af4671 0%, #a45cd1 100%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: url('#gooey');
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes circle__in {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.95, 1.05);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05, 0.95);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
  83% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.98, 1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

input:checked+.circle {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: circle__in;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.circle {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: circle__out;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

.circle--outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid white;
}

.circle--inner {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
}

@keyframes circle--inner__in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)translateX(80px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1)translateX(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)translateX(80px);
  }
}

input:checked+.circle .circle--inner {
  transform-origin: 50% -20%;
  animation-name: circle--inner__in;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes circle--inner__out {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(0.19);
  }
  99% {
    transform: scale(0.21);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

.circle--inner {
  animation-name: circle--inner__out;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.85, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.circle--inner__1 {
  transform-origin: -12% -8%;
}

.circle--inner__2 {
  transform-origin: -35% 50%;
}

.circle--inner__3 {
  transform-origin: 60% 130%;
}

.circle--inner__4 {
  transform-origin: 112% 90%;
}

.circle--inner__5 {
  transform-origin: 75% -30%;
}

// dribbble - twitter
.dribbble {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.twitter {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  right: 64px;
  bottom: 14px;
}

svg {
  fill: #1da1f2;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

label svg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__1" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__2" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__3" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__4" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__5" ></div>
    <div class="circle--outer" ></div>
  </div>
<svg>
    <defs>
      <filter id="gooey" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <feGaussianBlur
          in="SourceGraphic"
          result="blur"
          stdDeviation="3"
        />
        <feColorMatrix
          in="blur"
          mode="matrix"
          values="
            1 0 0 0 0
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 0 1 0 0
            0 0 0 18 -7
          "
          result="gooey"
        />
        <feBlend
          in2="gooey"
          in="SourceGraphic"
          result="mix"
        />
      </filter>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this doesn't appear to change anything in Safari... it also cuts them in half on Chrome (as seen on my site @ https://surgemovement.org/map)... any help?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your recommendation: https://jsfiddle.net/webmw/zct6rmd0/1/ and here is a screenshot of a test of this in Safari 14: https://i.imgur.com/XGhAuzt.png

Comment: @WebMW just give me some time i will try to rectify the error

Comment: @WebMW one thing though even if you remove whole `<svg id="gooey">--</svg>` still the code works the same

Comment: I just figured out the same... Can you ensure this is correct? I added an answer but will accept any other answer that can check to make sure this is implemented correctly with only CSS. Would like to award 50 points to someone so it doesn't go wasted.

Comment: @WebMW I just edited the answer see if it works for u

Comment: I know someone downvoted you. This might be for valid reasons. Time had ran out to the last minute on the bounty and I decided to award you the answer / rep points for the effort given. I don't see the difference you speak of when removing the SVG, however. Could you better explain what the purpose of the SVG was?

Comment: @WebMW you can see when you click the check box the circle moves up and down when it moves that way it is blending with the outer circle like if its a slime but when you remove the svg it won't(just see the moment the circle moves and comes in contact with outer circle)

Comment: @WebMW  just see the output of my code again i just edited it after looking at the output remove the filter from .circle and see the output again you will see the difference

Comment: Thanks Ac_mmi! That looks awesome, but it's unfortunately not supported in Safari. The only solution that I've found, as you also pointed out, is to remove the SVG entirely to prevent the checkbox from being blurred / fuzzy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The whole SVG & Filter don't even appear necessary in this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/webmw/zct6rmd0/8/

Is there any reason to have this SVG & Filter w/ a feGaussianBlur, feColorMatrix, or feBlend?

This appears to be working alone with pure CSS animation:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__1" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__2" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__3" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__4" ></div>
    <div class="circle--inner circle--inner__5" ></div>
    <div class="circle--outer" ></div>
  </div>
</label>
```

A better answer that extends on best practices with this CSS animation technique is welcome, and I will award you the 50 reputation points. Looking for maximum cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is clipping the output of the feGaussianBlur

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
    <filter x="-50%" width="200%" y="-50%" height="200%" id="gooey" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" />
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9"result="goo" />
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
    <g filter="url(#gooey)" class="top-circles">
        <circle class="top-circ" fill="#fff" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
        <circle class="second-circ" fill="#fff" cx="2" cy="2" r="1.6" />
        
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What are you referencing with id="goo"? I tried adding in your specified attributes into the filter's actual id="gooey" and it does not change the outcome in Safari.

Comment: @WebMW Updated, apologize.. I never usually answer questions, randomly landed on this searching for something else and had the same issue as you did.

Comment: Also I just saw your codepen, safari doesn't work well adding the effect on non svg elements. each one of the circles make into an svg circle like how I have above.

Comment: I tried adding your SVG to it, (still not sure if this was a proposed solution)... no luck with that: https://jsfiddle.net/webmw/zct6rmd0/12/

Answer (score -2):

add this tag

```
<filter id="gooey" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
```

replace this with

```
<filter id="gooey">
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to understand how to format your posts. But also, Ac_mmi already posted this 2 days ago.